# LUKS encryption, Allow reboot without Password

Tags: disk-encryption, luks

I know PGP has an option to set a parameter so that the next reboot won't ask for the encryption password.

I thought I saw the same functionality with LUKS/cryptsetup

But, as it always happens, When I need it I cant find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The password prompt during reboot isn't technically provided by `cryptsetup`, but by a script running within the boot-time `initrd`, which then calls `cryptsetup` with the password you supply.

Debian, at the very least, doesn't provide any such option, but you can modify your `initrd` to do whatever you want during the boot process.

`cryptsetup` has no facility for mounting a LUKS-formatted block device without a password, but it can accept a key file.  This could be the basis for automatic boot without a passphrase prompt.  Beware that if you store such a file on an unencrypted file system it can likely be easily recovered with undelete tools unless you `badblocks` and reformat whatever device it is stored on or something similar.